# GitHub API v3: Getting 404 error on creating issues

Tags: javascript, github, post, github-api

I'm following [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#create-an-issue) try to get issue list and post issues.

I've managed to get the issue list using

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/wheatup/wheatup.github.io/issues
```

But when I try to post an issue to the repo, I got a 404 error with following body:

```json
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/issues#create-an-issue"
}
```

Here's my post request:

#### URL

```
POST https://api.github.com/repos/wheatup/wheatup.github.io/issues
```

#### Headers

```
Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,zh-CN;q=0.9,zh;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6,sr;q=0.5,pl;q=0.4,la;q=0.3
Authorization: token d7fa1e545c*******************31957a97e06
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 79
Content-Type: application/json
DNT: 1
Host: api.github.com
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36
```

#### Body

```js
{ 
  title: "Test", 
  body: "test content", 
  labels: [], 
  assignees: [], 
  milestone: 1
}
```

This is how I post the request:

```js
const result = await axios.post('https://api.github.com/repos/wheatup/wheatup.github.io/issues', {
    title: 'Test',
    body: 'test content',
    labels: [],
    assignees: [],
    milestone: 1,
  }, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'token d7fa1e545c*******************31957a97e06',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'
    }
});
```

[My repo](https://github.com/wheatup/wheatup.github.io) is public, did I miss something? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are missing the github token in the request. I get 404 on my local until I add the bearer token. Then I get 401 because I am not using an actual bearer token to hit your repo. So once you add that part, it all should work.

**Solution 1:**

```
    const result = await axios.post('https://api.github.com/repos/wheatup/wheatup.github.io/issues', {
            title: 'Test',
            body: 'test content',
            // labels: [], --> Since empty, commented out as it is optional param
            // assignee: '', --> Since empty, commented out as it is optional param. Also you had a typo and this attributes expects string not array
            milestone: 1,
        }, {
        headers: {
           'Authorization': `Bearer ${githubToken}`,
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'
        }
    });
```

When dealing with github API, I would suggest use their toolkit instead because you only need to provide the token once and then subsequent request can just have the data provided to them

**Alternative Solution 2:** --> This only applies to not have to deal with passing bearer token on every request so ignore if you rather keep using axios.

```
  const octokit = new Octokit({ auth: githubToken });

  const response = await octokit.request('POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues', {
       owner: 'wheatup',
       repo: 'wheatup.github.io',
       title: 'Test',
       body: 'test content',
       milestone: 1,
  });
```

**EDIT**

***Solution 3:*** -> Actual solution to the problem provided above

When dealing with OAuth apps there are some steps to take

1. Users are redirected to request their GitHub identity
2. Users are redirected back to your site by GitHub
3. Your app accesses the API with the user's access token

NOTE: When calling the request identity make sure to require the scope necessary for the API calls to make. In this case the 404 was received due to token not having proper permissions to the repo as scope was missing.

More information about oauth API calls can be found here
https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/

Comment: Thanks for the help.Sorry I didn't point out that the token I've set in `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']`, so it's actually included. I've fixed the question. I tried both `token` and `Bearer` but still get the same 404 result

Comment: The tag for the token needs to be ***Bearer*** not ***token***. I updated my answer to let you know that I tested locally with the exact response I provided and I get proper responses.

Comment: I event tried the [octokit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@octokit/rest) but it still gives me 404, that's so weird... Did I forget to set something for my repo? Or it's a bug for me...

Comment: @HaoWu can you copy paste the exact axios call I made but add any string in front of ***Bearer***, running that simple call should give you 401. The we can confirm it’s a problem with how the token was created. If you still get 404, it’s something else entirely.

Comment: @HaoWu ok, make sure to delete that picture now that we verified what's going on and delete the current token you have created to avoid anyone else using it. I tested with your token and I get 404. Due to that fact, I think it's either a token creation issue or permission of your token issue. Take a look into this doc to get more information on how to create it, and to give the token edit access to ***issues*** source https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220597/discussion-between-edward-romero-and-hao-wu).

Comment: It's okay I've revoked the token. Thanks

Comment: Turns out it was because I didn't set the `repo` scope while authorizing my OAuth app, thanks so much <3